# Behavior of ifc function

Tags: if-statement, sas, lazy-evaluation

Can someone please explain the a weird behavior I observe with the `ifc` function :

I ran the following 3 tests:

```
data test1;
  var = "    "; /* 4 spaces */
  length outvar $5;
  if not missing(var) then outvar = substr(var, 1,5);
  else call missing(outvar);
  put outvar=;
run;

data test2;
  var = "    "; /* 4 spaces */
  length outvar $5;
  outvar = ifc(not missing(var), substr(var, 1, 5), "");
  put outvar=;
run;

data test3;
  var = "     "; /* 5 spaces */
  length outvar $5;
  outvar = ifc(not missing(var), substr(var, 1, 5), "");
  put outvar=;
run;
```

test1 and test3 run fine. However I get the following warning/note for test2:
`Invalid third argument to function SUBSTR`

While I understand the meaning of this, it is not clear why it is triggered to begin with given it should not go into evaluating that expression in the `ifc` function. Appears the `ifc` function is evaluating both expressions regardless of the outcome of logical test.

Comment: IFC/N evaluates all expressions in all arguments.  The SUBSTRN function should fix the message and give desired result.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think SAS has any places where it does NOT evaluate all expressions in a statement that is executed.  That is, SAS does not "short-circuit".

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys

Comment: This is also why LAG works in IFC/IFN but not in IF/THEN statements. It has it's benefits and downsides.

Comment: @data_null_ - if you could please post your comment as an answer, I will accept is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IFC/N evaluates all expressions in all arguments. The SUBSTRN function should fix the message and give desired result.

Answer (score 2):

## SAS does not use lazy-evaluation.

Before `ifc` is applied, SAS evaluates all its arguments,

### so if you submit

```
data test2;
  var = "    "; /* 4 spaces */
  length outvar $7;
  outvar = ifc(not missing(var), substr(var, 1, 5), "");
  put outvar=;
run;
```

SAS will evaluate

- `not missing(var)`, which results in false
- `substr(var, 1, 5)`, wich gives an error
- `""`, wich results in a null string

So the error occurs before the `ifc` is executed.

## But if you submit

```
data test1;
  var = "    "; /* 4 spaces */
  length outvar $5;
  if not missing(var) then outvar = substr(var, 1,5);
  else call missing(outvar);
  put outvar=;
run;
```

SAS will evaluate `not missing(var)`, which results in false.
Next it will

- not evaulate `substr(var, 1, 5)`
- but only evaluate `""`, wich results in a null string